# PHP mysql issue in creating an upload picture to blob undefined index _FILES

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I've read about 15 threads on here, tried each and none have worked yet, the issue seems to be around uploading a picture using blob (yes I know that I shouldn't and as it scales it will cause a problem but this is only a prototype). Seem that even though I am passing in the file, $_FILES['picture'] is not set. If i remove the if and get to something like  $imageName = $_FILES['picture']['name']; it says the index pictures does not exist. Any help would be appreciated greatly, thanks.

Here is my html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php include ('header.php'); ?>
<title>Add item</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Add item:</h1>

<form method="post" action="additem.php">
Item Name:
<input type="varchar" name="name" maxlength=64>
<br><br>

Description:<br>
<textarea name="description">
</textarea>
<br><br>

Date added:
<input type="date" name="date">
<br><br>

Picture:
<input type="file" name="picture" value="picture">
<br><br>

Shop:
<input type="varchar" name="shop" maxlength=64>
<br><br>

Type:
<input type="varchar" name="type" maxlength=15>
<br><br>

subtype:
<input type="varchar" name="subtype" maxlength=32>
<br><br>

<input type="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="submit" value="Add event">
</form>
<br><br>
```

and my php code:

```
<?php

if (empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo "Not logged in";
    exit;
}  else {
    if ($_SESSION['privilege'] == "student") {
        echo $_SESSION['username'];
        echo " does not have permission to create events ";
        exit;
    } else {
        echo $_SESSION['username'];
        echo " creating new item";
    }
}

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    require_once('connectdb.php');

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if(empty($name)) {
        echo(" You must enter an item name.");
        exit;
    }

    $date = $_POST['date'];
    if(empty($date)) {
        echo(" You must enter an item add date.");
        exit;
    }


    $shop= $_POST['shop'];
    if(empty($venue)) {
        echo(" You must enter an shop.");
        exit;
    }

    if (isset($_FILES['picture'])){
    $imageName = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
    $imageData = $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'];
    $imageType = $_FILES['picture']['type'];

    if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image")
    {
        echo "this is an image";
    } else {
        echo "Incorrect file type";
        exit;
    }

    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $subtype = $_POST['subtype'];
    $organiser = $_SESSION['username'];


    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `items` (`name`, `description`, `date`, `picturename`, `picture`, `organiser`, `shop`, `type`, `subtype`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->execute(array($name, $description, $date, $imageName, $imageData, $_SESSION['username'], $shop, $type, $subtype));
        echo("Successful.");
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo("Failed to save data to database.<br>");
        echo($ex->getMessage());
        exit;
    }
    }else{
        echo "file not set";
    }

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify a non-default encoding for your form - otherwise the browser will not upload your file at all:

```
<form method="post" action="additem.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```